# Why is my firefox extension messing with another one's buttons?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I wrote a firefox extension which simply re-formats a page using some JQuery.  But, it's interfering with another extension that places a button on the header panel of the browser.  Now that button doesn't display.  Can some one point me in the right direction as to when this happens.  This is my first fire-fox extension.

---

**Update:**

The problem is actually being caused by the JQuery source file.

[This is a known issue when using JQuery in the overlay](http://dev2.taboca.com/en/technotes/extensions-with-jquery/firefox-extensions-and-jquery.html).

Comment: well, it could be anything. what about posting some code to help us help you?

Answer (score 1):

Your update doesn't include valid chrome.manifest lines.  Also, your original style line was totally wrong, and likely the cause of your problem.  You should review [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#Manifest_Instructions) which specifies the syntax to see how this should have been done.

Comment: Thanks for the link. What I did fixed it so I'm leaving it as is for now.

Comment: but you are registering a style package for chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul which is absolutely bogus.  The behavior there is going to be very very strange.